# How to show recent directories on separate lines in echo area?

Tags: dired, echo-area, message, recentf

Linux Mint 20,
Emacs 27.2

Install package dired, dired+

I want to show recent directories visited in the minibuffer. Something like this:

[image]

I tried this:

```lisp
    (defun my-recent-dir ()
      (interactive)
      (message "Recent dirs: %S" (diredp-recent-dirs nil)))
```

with this result:

[image]

But I instead want to see each directory on its own line in the echo area.

Answer (score 1):

```lisp
(defun bar ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((dirs  (diredp-recent-dirs nil)))
    (message "Recent dirs: \n%s" 
             (mapconcat #'identity dirs "\n"))))
```

Comment: Yes, but it only show recent dir. But how I can select it?

Comment: There was no mention of selecting anything in the question. If you want an answer to *that* question, then ask *that* question (separately now - it's always a bad idea to move the goal posts after the question has been answered).

Comment: In general, the questions you've asked so far are not very clear. You don't specify what you're looking for; you just say a few words and expect others to guess exactly what you mean. Try to provide a step-by-step recipe of what you've tried, saying what you see at each step and what you expect/want to see instead.